# Linear Feedback Shift Register

Tags: c#, cryptography

I haven't found any implementation in C# of the LFSR so accordling to Wikipedia i have implment it to myself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

My implementation accept some parameter so can be adapted to various feedback polynomials (my refernce table)

https://web.archive.org/web/20161007061934/http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/csce680/walker/lfsr_table.pdf

For the testing pahse i generate as many number as the cycle will allow before a repetiton (i use a byte to my testing purpose).

---

### **EDITED (PROBLEM SOLVED IT WAS DUE A TYPO, QUESTION REPHRASED AT THE END)**

The strange thing is in my test the period is exactly half of what expected/declared by the paper (not (2^n)-1 but 2^(n-1)).

---

Here is my LFSR implementation

```
public class Register
{
    private bool[] _register = null ;
    private bool[] _feedbackPoints = new bool[256] ;
    private int _registerLength = 0 ;

    public Register ( int length, int [] feedbackPoints ) : this ( length , feedbackPoints , new byte [0] ) {}

    public Register ( int length, int [] feedbackPoints, byte [] seed )
    {
        if ( length > 256 )
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "length" , "Alloewed vaues need to be between 1 and 256" ) ;

        _registerLength = length ;

        _register = new bool[length] ;

        foreach ( int feedbackPoint in feedbackPoints )
            if ( feedbackPoint > 256 )
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "feedbackPoints", "Alloewed vaues of item of array need to be between 1 and 256" ) ;
            else 
                _feedbackPoints[feedbackPoint] = true ;


        byte [] randomizedSeed = this.SeedRandomization ( seed ) ;

        string temporaryRegisterRepresantation = string.Empty ;
        foreach ( byte seedItem in randomizedSeed )
            temporaryRegisterRepresantation += Convert.ToString ( seedItem , 2 ) ;

        int index = 0 ;
        foreach ( char bit in temporaryRegisterRepresantation )
            if ( index < length )
                _register[index++] = bit == '1' ;
    }

    public bool Clock ()
    {
        lock ( this )
        {
            bool output = _register[0] ;

            for ( int index = 0; index < _registerLength - 1; index++ )
                _register[index] = _feedbackPoints[index] ? _register [index+1] ^ output : _register [index+1] ;

            _register [_registerLength - 1] = output ;

            return output ;
        }
    }

    private byte[] SeedRandomization ( byte[] inputSeed )
    {
        SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed ();
        int seedLength = inputSeed.Length ;

        byte [] seed = new byte [seedLength] ;
        Array.Copy ( inputSeed , seed , seedLength ) ;


        Array.Resize<byte> ( ref seed , seedLength + 4 ) ;
        byte[] dateTime = BitConverter.GetBytes ( DateTime.Now.Ticks ) ;
        seed[seedLength] = dateTime[0] ;
        seed[seedLength+1] = dateTime[1] ;
        seed[seedLength+2] = dateTime[2] ;
        seed[seedLength+3] = dateTime[3] ;

        return sha256.ComputeHash ( seed , 0 , seed.Length ) ;
    }
}
```

And there is my testing code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main ( string [] args )
    {
        Dictionary<int, bool> tester = new Dictionary<int, bool> ();
        List<int> duplicate = new List<int> ();

        Register register_1 = new Register ( 8 , new int[] { 5,4,3 } ) ;

        for ( int index = 0; index < 256; index++ )
        {
            bool b00 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b01 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b02 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b03 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b04 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b05 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b06 = register_1.Clock ();
            bool b07 = register_1.Clock ();

            BitArray bitArray = new BitArray ( new bool [] { b00, b01, b02, b03, b04, b05, b06, b07 } );
            int [] array = new int [1];
            bitArray.CopyTo ( array, 0 );

            if ( !tester.ContainsKey ( array[0] ) )
                tester.Add ( array [0], true ) ;
            else 
                duplicate.Add ( array[0] ) ;
        }

        duplicate = duplicate.OrderBy ( x => x ).ToList() ;
    }
}
```

I have manually followed the implementation with 2bit LFSR and i see nothing wrong about it, so i would ask if there are any fallacies in my test or implementation.

---

**EDITED**

I have found my fault, i have omitted to write b00 so is correct that the period is exactly half of what expected.

I keep the code but renew my question, now i wold ask if you found any issue with current implementation (that seems to work with current test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally agree with @Maxim about the spacing but need to say, that you didn't use spaces where you should for the sake of readability.
This

> ```
> seed[seedLength] = dateTime[0] ;
> seed[seedLength+1] = dateTime[1] ;
> seed[seedLength+2] = dateTime[2] ;
> seed[seedLength+3] = dateTime[3] ;
> ```

would be more readable if you place spaces like so

```
seed[seedLength] = dateTime[0];
seed[seedLength + 1] = dateTime[1];
seed[seedLength + 2] = dateTime[2];
seed[seedLength + 3] = dateTime[3];
```

---

Omitting braces `{}`, although they might be optional, can lead to hidden and therefor hard to track bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them. This will avoid hidden bugs and the code looks better structured.

---

`SeedRandomization ()`

The `SHA256Managed` class implements `IDisposable` through inheriting  `HashAlgorithm` so you should enclose its usage in a `using` block.

---

These variables

> ```
> private bool[] _register = null ;
> private bool[] _feedbackPoints = new bool[256] ;
> private int _registerLength = 0 ;
> ```

should be made `readonly` because they won't change anywhere except in the constructor.

---

A little LINQ *could* simplify this

> ```
> foreach ( int feedbackPoint in feedbackPoints )
>     if ( feedbackPoint > 256 )
>         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "feedbackPoints", "Alloewed vaues of item of array need to be between 1 and 256" ) ;
>     else 
>         _feedbackPoints[feedbackPoint] = true ;
> ```

but do you spot the spelling error which happened by using copy&pasta not carefully ?

At least I would place the part about `feedbackPoint > 256` at the top of the constructor where the input parameter validation belongs.

A simple

```
if (feedbackPoints.Any(p => p > 256)) 
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "feedbackPoints", "Allowed vaues of item of array need to be between 1 and 256" ) ;
}
```

could do the validation.

But what about the `length` parameter ? Passing `length == -1` seems valid but will throw an `OverflowException` at `_register = new bool[length] ;`.

In addition the messages of the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`'s states "..... need to be between 1 and 256" but you only check in both cases `value > 256` without checking the lower boundaries. If I read "**between** 1 and 256" I will think that the allowed values are `2...255` but this could be because I am not native english.

---

> ```
> string temporaryRegisterRepresantation = string.Empty ;
> foreach ( byte seedItem in randomizedSeed )
>     temporaryRegisterRepresantation += Convert.ToString ( seedItem , 2 ) ;
> ```

each time `string += string` happens a new string object is created because strings are immutable. If you want to concatenate strings in a loop most of the times it is better (time and space) to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Since I'm not native English speaker too you got me interested in the "between" meaning and I found this post: ["Between A and B" or "from A to B"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b) :)

Comment: @Heslacher thanks for your review, expecially for the hint about readonly variables. I didn't know that a readonly variable can be assigned in the custructor.
Thanks a lot for underline my blunder in boundaries check, reading that part of code twice i found a lot of problems indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Just some notes about the code.

Read this: [Why is lock(this) {…} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad).

Also why do you use so many spaces? :) `if ( !tester.ContainsKey ( array[0] ) )` looks strange, it is far from common practice. 99.9% of C# programmers will write it like

```
if (!tester.ContainsKey(array[0]))
```

In this code

> ```
> List<int> duplicate = new List<int> ();
> ...
> duplicate = duplicate.OrderBy ( x => x ).ToList() ;
> ```

you don't need `OrderBy` since the `List<T>` provides `Sort` method which doesn't require additional memory allocation.

I recommend to use `var` for all variables where the type is obvious from the right part of expression. I hope you'll agree that

```
var tester = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
var duplicate = new List<int>();
```

is nicer than

> ```
> Dictionary<int, bool> tester = new Dictionary<int, bool> ();
> List<int> duplicate = new List<int> ();
> ```

Also consider using [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Array.Copy` for byte arrays. It will improve performance.

Comment: i have read the article about the bad of lock(this), interesting but i doubt that is an issue in my situation (anyway it has really a cost zero the effort needed to modify my code, so probably i'll do; surely i'll keep in mind the drawback underlined in the article).
Thanks for the Buffer.BlockCopy suggestion.